# Interbase driver (Firebird) on Windows PHP

Tags: php, web, firebird

I know have so much questions about it but i don't find the right answer for that searching here and in other websites sorry but I tried all.
How to install Interbase on PHP because I have that php.ini and I added the line extension=php_interbase.dll or without .dll and don't work
I copy the files who people say to C:\Windows\System32.
I already have installed FB 2.5.

[My php.ini](https://paste.sh/onoTJQoB#jOsRFjkaBkz1yKCFyUoaI5oA)

[Firebird driver](https://firebirdsql.org/en/php-driver/)

I have apache as service without Xampp, Wampp etc... And PHP 7.4.
I already connected PHP to Apache24.
How to make the interbase work on PHP?
The only way that works is using EasyPHP but i need to do this on a server...
Thanks for all people who take a time to answer.

Comment: Does your error log say anything about not finding php_interbase.dll? What does `php -i` say about Interbase?

Comment: @AndrewSchulman Nothing, don't show any line with interbase. PHP not see the extension on that php -i or phpinfo. I added the link of driver in the question...